# How can I find a sink that will fit where an old sink was?

Tags: kitchens, sinkhole

We wish to rid ourselves of an 'American Standard Americast' kitchen sink and go with an over-the-counter sink.  We have a granite counter top that cannot be changed and therein lays an issue as the current opening is "set in stone."  The current sink, 'Americast' model number 7145, has become scarred and ugly in appearance even after being treated with a paint to recover its original look.
The sink has two unequally sized bowls; the left side being the 'deep end' and the right side being the 'shallow end.'  The current opening measures 29.5 inches wide, 18.5 inches on the 'deep side' height, 16 inches on the 'shallow side' height, with rounded corners, and the bend of the granite top centered at 21 inches in the transfer from shallow to deep.  There are four openings for the faucet, water control, soap, and spray attachments that are 2.25 inches back from the shallow-end edge.  Measuring from the left, the openings are at the 10.5, 14.625, 18.875, and 22.875 inch marks.
Question is "where do I find a replacement overmount sink without having to order a customized sink from a manufacturer?

Comment: Why not cut a paper template resembling the opening shape and take it to you local Home Depot equivalent for finding a match?

Comment: Leave open.  This is actually a not uncommon problem.  I think the question could be edited to make it less of a shop for me, but it is useful information.

Comment: You have virtually no chance finding this at a big box.  You might be able to find this online.  I think that you have a better chance at finding an undermount because offset doubles are usually undermounted on stone - and with undermount your 4 holes don't come into play.  You need to do a lot of googling and calling manufacturers.  Might also call a local granite place or plumbing company to see if they have something to fit.  If you were willing to cut the granite to rectangle your choices would open up.

Answer (score -2):

"Farm Sink" solution to your problem is to replace sink with a Farm Sink or get your old sink refinished at a used appliance store